# VBA AutoFilter hiding all rows - including the ones matching criteria

Tags: vba, excel, autofilter

I'm applying VBA AutoFilter to some results in an excel sheet. It seems to compile properly, but when I check the results, the AutoFilter is hiding both the rows that match and that do not match the criteria I applied.

If I manually select the autofilter that was applied, i see that the criteria that I coded is correctly input and, by just clicking enter, the criteria matching rows show.

I'm using a Brazilian Portuguese version of Excel, not sure if that might be the issue.

Here's what I've tried:

```
Sub FilterOff(ByVal thisSheet)
    thisSheet.Activate
    With thisSheet
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:F1").AutoFilter
        .Range("A1:F1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=">0.01", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="<-0.01"
        .Range("A1:F1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=">100"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Tried your code and worked perfectly for me. I don't think your error is in that part of the code. Are you calling it with the correct Sheet?

Comment: I'm using something like: `Option Explicit    Dim thisSheet As Worksheet    Set thisSheet = Sheets("thisSheet")    thisSheet.AutoFilterMode = False    FilterOff thisSheet`

Comment: Tried that part as well and it works. I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: answer from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50331302/date-filter-hiding-all-cells-through-excel-vba helped me

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing something similar in one of my macros.  I had a table that I was trying to autofilter.  I could do it manually, but not in VBA, even when I was exactly replicating what the recording function gave me.  I also could not copy+paste as values in VBA, but I could manually.

What worked for me was to save and close the workbook, then reopen it and apply the autofilter. Specifically, I used this:

```
tempWb.SaveAs ("dir\temp.xlsx")
tempWb.Close (0)
Set rptWb = Workbooks.Open("dir\temp.xlsx")
Set rptWs = rptWb.Sheets(1)
rptWs.Range(rptWs.Cells(1, 1), rptWs.Cells(lstRow, lstCol)).AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:="=NO RECORD"
```

and it worked.

Update: I think the underlying issue was that I had calculation set to manual.  After I set calculation to automatic, the problems went away.

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this and it worked

```
Range("A1:B6").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$6").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=10", _
        Operator:=xlOr, Criteria2:="=30"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$B$6").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="100"
```

Comment: I tried your code here but got the same problem. But thanks for the suggestion anyway.