# Date Filter Hiding All Cells Through Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I'm using the below to filter out specific dates however it hides all cells and does not leave in the required Data.  When completed manually it works fine it also works when I change the range to the last row(**$AL1210**) however this range will increase as I will be pasting in new data daily.

I am trying to find a solution for the range to ideally automatically increase to last row(although I've tried this from other answers and get the same result, as I don't understand why the filter does not work, can anyone help me with this?

```
Sub Auto_Filter()
    `Auto_Filter Macro
    `This Auto Filters all data for years 2017 & 2018, this also sorts to newest date first
    Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+A
    Sheets("Paste Data").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$AL$10000").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:= _
        ">=01/01/2017", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=31/12/2018"
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Paste Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Paste Data").AutoFilter.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:= _
        Range("I1:I10000"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlDescending, DataOption _
        :=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Paste Data").AutoFilter.Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: use "yyyy/mm/dd" date format in your code

Comment: I believe you can just use `.range("A1").autofilter`

Comment: Try replacing the hard-coded ranges with dynamic ranges. then at least you can see what's going on within Excel itself.

Answer (score 1):

use "yyyy/mm/dd" date format in your code – JK2017

Works Thanks

Comment: That'll stop 01/12/2017 being translated to 12th January / 1st December, but it won't expand the range to include new rows - that'll be either @DavesExcel answer, or a dynamic named range using `INDEX` & `COUNTA`.

Comment: 10,000 rows should be more than enough

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to set the range dynamically.

```
Dim rng As Range, sh As Worksheet
Set sh = Sheets("Paste Data")
With sh
    Set rng = .Range("A1:AL" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "AL").End(xlUp).Row)

End With
```